# Calling non-static method from another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static-methods

pardon the messy code, I'm learning how to edit a template application. There is a lot of code not doing anything.

Basically I'm trying to move a string called sBuffer to the Activity class to display the data on the screen in a textview. The function gets called in my TemplateManager.

I've been stuck on this problem for quite awhile and help would be very much appreciated.

I don't know how to call my onDataReceived function that is in TemplateDataCallback in TemplateManager without making my onDataReceived static. When it is static I can't use the intents to move around the data.

### Tried kunlun's idea of adding (new TemplateDataCallback()).onDataReceived(device, data);

it compiled, installed, ran and crashed when data came in.
Notifications enabled successfully
2020-07-16 09:58:40.591 20526-20539/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:C3:7B:D6:A0:27 interval=39 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
2020-07-16 09:58:40.591 20526-20539/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox I/BleManager: Connection parameters updated (interval: 48.75ms, latency: 0, timeout: 5000ms)
2020-07-16 09:58:41.699 20526-20539/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox I/BleManager: Notification received from 6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e, value: (0x) 64-66-67-0D
2020-07-16 09:58:41.704 20526-20526/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox D/ascii: onDataReceived:dfg
2020-07-16 09:58:41.705 20526-20526/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-07-16 09:58:41.709 20526-20526/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox, PID: 20526
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4697)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4654)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5015)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4983)
at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.template.callback.TemplateDataCallback.onDataReceived(TemplateDataCallback.java:42)
at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.template.TemplateManager$TemplateManagerGattCallback.lambda$initialize$3(TemplateManager.java:84)
at no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.template.-$$Lambda$TemplateManager$TemplateManagerGattCallback$AaM3yOzPmG7Maq2q-1Ltp4MIo4Q.onDataReceived(Unknown Source:0)
at no.nordicsemi.android.ble.ValueChangedCallback.lambda$notifyValueChanged$0(ValueChangedCallback.java:147)
at no.nordicsemi.android.ble.-$$Lambda$ValueChangedCallback$4rcq0bbOhcTVqpLmftoy8pUEJ-Q.run(Unknown Source:6)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
2020-07-16 09:58:45.688 20526-20539/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=FE:C3:7B:D6:A0:27 interval=60 latency=0 timeout=400 status=0
2020-07-16 09:58:45.688 20526-20539/no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox I/BleManager: Connection parameters updated (interval: 75.0ms, latency: 0, timeout: 4000ms)

========================================================================================

This is my class where the data is being captured.

public abstract class TemplateDataCallback extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static String sBuffer;
private static String bstr;
private static String MainString;
public static String ascii;

public void onDataReceived(@NonNull final BluetoothDevice device, @NonNull final Data data) {

    bstr = new String (String.valueOf(data));
    int istr = bstr.length();
    MainString = bstr.substring(5,istr); // split string into hex
    String dashless = MainString.replaceAll("\\-",""); // remove dashes
    ascii = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < dashless.length(); i += 2) {

        String part = dashless.substring(i, i + 2);   // extract two characters from hex string
        char ch = (char)Integer.parseInt(part, 16); // change it into base 16 and typecast as the character
        ascii = ascii + ch;  // add this char to final ASCII string
    }

    Log.d("ascii", "onDataReceived:"+ascii);
    sBuffer = ascii;

    Intent intent = new Intent(TemplateDataCallback.this, TemplateActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATA",sBuffer);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

## }

This is the part of the where I'm erroring not being able to call my onDataReceived function.
Error noted by **, Message is "Non-static method 'onDataReceived(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, no.nordicsemi.android.ble.data.Data)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

public class TemplateManager extends BatteryManager {

```
static final UUID SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"); // UART Service ID
private static final UUID MEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"); // UART TX Service
private static final UUID READABLE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A38-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // Body Sensor Location
private static final UUID OTHER_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // Generic Access service
private static final UUID WRITABLE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); // Device Name

private BluetoothGattCharacteristic requiredCharacteristic, deviceNameCharacteristic, optionalCharacteristic;

public String sBuffer;

public TemplateManager(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
protected BatteryManagerGattCallback getGattCallback() {
    return new TemplateManagerGattCallback();
}

private class TemplateManagerGattCallback extends BatteryManagerGattCallback {

    @Override
    protected void initialize() {

        super.initialize();

        requestMtu(260)
                .with((device, mtu) -> log(LogContract.Log.Level.APPLICATION, "MTU changed to " + mtu))
                .done(device -> {

                })
                .fail((device, status) -> log(Log.WARN, "MTU change not supported"))
                .enqueue();

        setNotificationCallback(requiredCharacteristic)
                .with((device, data) -> {
                    TemplateDataCallback.**onDataReceived**(device, data); // ERROR onDataRecived 
                });

        enableNotifications(requiredCharacteristic)
                .with((device, data) -> log(Log.DEBUG, "Data sent: " + data))
                .done(device -> log(LogContract.Log.Level.APPLICATION, "Notifications enabled successfully"))
                .fail((device, status) -> log(Log.WARN, "Failed to enable notifications"))
                .enqueue();
    }
```

========================================================================================

Comment: Pretty sure all you have to do here is remove 'TemplateDataCallback' and it'll work. Otherwise, try 'TemplateDataCallback.this.onDataReceived'.

Comment: To call a non-static method you need to have a reference of that class, and call the method from that reference.

Comment: @rzwitserloot onDataReceived is in a different class so it needs to be accessed with TemplateDataCallback I believe. adding this didn't seem to do it sadly.

Comment: @KunLun, do you happen to know of a good example I could reference off of? I'm fairly new, lots to learn.

Comment: You could try `(new TemplateDataCallback()).onDataReceived(...);` or if you need multiple uses you can save as variable `TemplateDataCallback tdcb = new TemplateDataCallback();` and call `tdcb.onDataReceived(...);`

Comment: @KunLun, oh it complied and ran! It crashed as soon as data came in. It got through the function and did a log before it crashed though.

Comment: If you have an error, you could identify the problem and fix it.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the intent. It doesn't like to start an startActivity() in a static.